# Width of line after text, depending on width of text

Tags: html, css

I want the width of the line calculated, depending of the width of the text. This is what i have now:

```css
h1 {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif !important;
    color: #de361b !important;
    font-size: 25px;
    margin-bottom: 20px !important;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-align:center;
}

h1:after {
    content: ' ';
    display: block;
    height: 1px;
    background-color: #de361b;
    margin-top: 15px;
    width: 60%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<h1>Bierhalle Schepens heet u welkom!</h1>

<h1>Promoties van de maand</h1>
```

So as you can see, the width of the line doesn't depend on the text width. This is what i want:

[image]

Is there an easy way to achieve this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: That looks like the text and line have the same width to me

Comment: In the screenshot the second line is smaller (depending on the lenght of the text h1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add padding to your Text tags and set the `border-bottom` attribute to each with the same colour. If you do, say, `padding-left:5px;padding-right:5px;` and set the `border-bottom` to `1px solid {your colour}`, it should look exactly how you want it.

Comment: I always use it myself, happy I could help! :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `text-decoration: underline` instead:

```css
h1 {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif !important;
  color: #de361b !important;
  font-size: 25px;
  margin-bottom: 20px !important;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: underline;/*add this property*/
}
```

```html
<h1>Bierhalle Schepens heet u welkom!</h1>

<h1>Promoties van de maand</h1>
```

Alternative you can add a `span` element and use `border-bottom`:

```css
h1 {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif !important;
  color: #de361b !important;
  font-size: 25px;
  margin-bottom: 20px !important;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-align: center;
}
h1 span {
  border-bottom: 3px solid;
  padding: 0 20px 5px 20px;
  
}
```

```html
<h1><span>Bierhalle Schepens heet u welkom!</span></h1>


<h1><span>Promoties van de maand</span></h1>
```

Comment: thanks; but this uses the exact width of the text. In the screenshot you can see the line is larger than the width of the text.

Comment: @JacobVanAchter You can adjust this adding `padding-left` and `padding-right`.

Comment: Okay, i can see this working too. I prefer the checked solution since i work in a CMS and i don't want my end users to start fiddling with html code.

Answer (score 0):

Introducing a `span` allows for the pseudo-element to be positioned absolutely and be wider than the parent.

```css
h1 {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif !important;
  color: #de361b !important;
  font-size: 25px;
  margin-bottom: 20px !important;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-align: center;
}
h1 span {
  position: relative;
}
h1 span:after {
  content: ' ';
  position: absolute;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #de361b;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  bottom: -5px;
  width: 120%;
}
```

```html
<h1><span>Bierhalle Schepens heet u welkom!</span></h1>

<h1><span>Promoties van de maand</span></h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

For the h1 only you have to add border-bottom and add a padding, like the example. You don't need use the :after in this case.

Then you can separate with divs and put the h1 like "inline-block" and center content for obtain the result like the image attached.

```css
.item {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 20px
}
.item:nth-child(even) {
  background: #f0f0f0;
}
h1 {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif !important;
  color: #de361b;
  font-size: 25px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  border-bottom: solid 1px red;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
  <h1>Bierhalle Schepens heet u welkom!</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit, at, maiores. Corporis quam, odio vel molestias optio error accusamus. Aliquam.</p>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <h1>Promoties van de maand</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit, at, maiores. Corporis quam, odio vel molestias optio error accusamus. Aliquam.</p>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <h1>test item!</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit, at, maiores. Corporis quam, odio vel molestias optio error accusamus. Aliquam.</p>
</div>
```

You can edit and see the demo [here](http://codepen.io/rafalito1989/pen/ojGdwR)

Regards!